# Does Coral Edge TPU dev board supports AT + STA dual mode

Tags: google-coral

Want to go with Coral Edge TPU dev board.
but like to know does Coral Edge TPU dev board supports AT + STA dual mode?

Regards,
Prashant

Answer (score 0):

Coral Dev board uses "Murata LBEE5U91CQ module". And this chip does support dual mode network topology (AP + STA). Please see the details at : https://wireless.murata.com/type-1cq.html.

However, we have only used the dev board as STA so far.